# Batch command to rename filenames like 'The Kids Performances (2020).mp4' to 'Kids Performances, The (2020).mp4'

Tags: video, batch-rename

My family has recordings of the children's performances in school and extracurricular activities saved over the years as primarily `.avi` and `.mp4` files. I have been asked to take all these files (there are well over a hundred of them) and relabel any video that starts with the word `The` or `A` and move it to the end.

For example, a video titled `The Kids Performances (2020).mp4` would be changed to `Kids Performances, The (2020).mp4`. I have no idea why they want to keep the words `The` and 'A' in the titles at all, but they do.

I’m using Windows and found a relatively simple method on a board on this site that I can use to get rid of the `The`  at the beginning of the titles, but I cannot figure out a way to move it to the back of the title before the year recorded which is always listed as (year).

Here’s what I am talking about:

```
for %%i in ("*.mp4") do (set fname=%%i) & call :rename
goto :eof
:rename
::Cuts off 1st four chars, then appends prefix
ren "%fname%" "%fname:~4%"
goto :eof
```

This takes care of removing the first 4 characters from the titles in a batch format, but I am having trouble moving those first 4 characters to the end of the title before the year. I have pleaded with my family members to just leave these words out of the title all together, but I cannot convince them.

I have Python installed on the PC as well if that would provide an easier method to achieve this goal. Thank you in advance to anyone able to assist!

Comment: Do **all** the files have `(YYYY)` at the end of the name?

Comment: Would this be as expected?
https://s3.gifyu.com/images/The_And_A.png

Comment: You sir get a +1 from me just for using `call` and `goto :EOF` (preventing the need for delayed expansion regardless of what you do in the labeled block).

Comment: Yes, all the files have (YYYY) at the end of the name.

Comment: s3.gifyu.com/images/The_And_A.png – Ricardo Bohner  YES that is exactly what I am looking for!!!

Comment: https://superuser.com/users/137093/ricardo-bohner - Would you be willing to share how you did that or provide us a link if you've already put it up on this site? It would be greatly appreciated. Thank you again!

Comment: @olpdog  use @ + user ....

Answer (score 9):

**PowerShell** with easily expandable Article list & extension list (We can  use [`-whatIf`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-7.1#parameters) for testing and then later delete it to execute our changes.)

```
$ArticleList = @( 'A' , 'The' )
$ExtList     = @( '*.avi' , '*.mp4' )
# From folder with files
# Remove "-WhatIf" to execute after testing
gci $ExtList | 
   ? { $_.BaseName -match ( '^({0})\s(\.+)\s(\(\d+\))' -f ( $ArticleList -join '|' )) } | 
       ReName-Item -NewName { '{0}, {1} {3}{4}' -f $matches[2] , $matches[1] , $matches[3] , $_.Extension -WhatIf }
```

`'^({0})\s(\.+)\s(\(\d+\))' -f ( $ArticleList -join '|' )`

creates a regex

`'^(Article[0]|Article[1]{|...})\s(\.+)\s(\(\d+\))'`

with three matching groups:

- `Article  : ({0})`
- `TitleTExt: \s(\.+)`
- `(Year)   : (\(\d+\))`

used to construct the newname.

Answer (score 0):

Not an automated solution as the one posted by Keith Miller, but as someone who wrote enough cmd scripts to know I don’t want  to write another one, I would use Excel for this:

1. Open the cmd prompt and navigate to the folder with the files to rename.
2. Copy the list of filename to the clipboard using
   `dir /b | clip` (or `dir /b /s | clip` if the files are saved in subdirectories)
   and paste this into Excel.
3. Save the new filenames into another column using whatever formulas you need. If you cannot do it fully automatically you can always tweak the results manually where necessary.
4. Once you are happy with the new filenames make an Excel formula for renaming the files one by one.
   At this stage the sheet could look similar to:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Formulas: |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Original filename | Prefix | Year | Extension | Rest of filename | New filename | Command |
| 3 | A Kids Performance (2018).avi | =IF(OR(UPPER(LEFT(A3;2))="A ";UPPER(LEFT(A3;4))="THE ");LEFT(A3;FIND(" ";A3)-1);"") | =MID(A3;FIND("(";A3)+1;4) | =RIGHT(A3;3) | =MID(A3;IF(B3="";1;LEN(B3)+2);LEN(A3)-LEN(B3)-LEN(C3)-LEN(D3)-IF(B3="";4;5)) | =E3&IF(B3="";"";", "&B3)&" ("&C3&")."&D3 | ="ren """&A3&""" """&F3&"""" |
| 4 | Some Kids Performance (2019).mkv | =IF(OR(UPPER(LEFT(A4;2))="A ";UPPER(LEFT(A4;4))="THE ");LEFT(A4;FIND(" ";A4)-1);"") | =MID(A4;FIND("(";A4)+1;4) | =RIGHT(A4;3) | =MID(A4;IF(B4="";1;LEN(B4)+2);LEN(A4)-LEN(B4)-LEN(C4)-LEN(D4)-IF(B4="";4;5)) | =E4&IF(B4="";"";", "&B4)&" ("&C4&")."&D4 | ="ren """&A4&""" """&F4&"""" |
| 5 | The Kids Performances (2020).mp4 | =IF(OR(UPPER(LEFT(A5;2))="A ";UPPER(LEFT(A5;4))="THE ");LEFT(A5;FIND(" ";A5)-1);"") | =MID(A5;FIND("(";A5)+1;4) | =RIGHT(A5;3) | =MID(A5;IF(B5="";1;LEN(B5)+2);LEN(A5)-LEN(B5)-LEN(C5)-LEN(D5)-IF(B5="";4;5)) | =E5&IF(B5="";"";", "&B5)&" ("&C5&")."&D5 | ="ren """&A5&""" """&F5&"""" |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1 | Values: |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 | Original filename | Prefix | Year | Extension | Rest of filename | New filename | Command |
| 3 | A Kids Performance (2018).avi | A | 2018 | avi | Kids Performance | Kids Performance, A (2018).avi | ren "A Kids Performance (2018).avi" "Kids Performance, A (2018).avi" |
| 4 | Some Kids Performance (2019).mkv |  | 2019 | mkv | Some Kids Performance | Some Kids Performance (2019).mkv | ren "Some Kids Performance (2019).mkv" "Some Kids Performance (2019).mkv" |
| 5 | The Kids Performances (2020).mp4 | The | 2020 | mp4 | Kids Performances | Kids Performances, The (2020).mp4 | ren "The Kids Performances (2020).mp4" "Kids Performances, The (2020).mp4" |

5. Select the cells with the calculated commands (in the above example G3:G5) and copy them to put them into the clipboard and either right click in the command prompt window (you might need to press enter on the last line) or paste the clipboard contents in an empty *.cmd or *.bat file, save it the folder with the files to be renamed and run it.